# Can't uninstall Bright VPN

Tags: windows-10, vpn, uninstall, revo-uninstaller

I recently found a VPN on my PC called **BrightVPN**, I never installed this one, not even when some softwares suggests others during installation.

I can't find it in ***control panel > programs***, ***Revo Uninstaller PRO*** also can't find it. plus it starts when I boot my PC and is not even on the startup list. (thx in advance).
[image]

Comment: Somebody installed it.  If it not anywhere to uninstall, probably best to back up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: Check if Bulk Crap Uninstaller detects it, usually it's better than Revo. If not, try scanning for malware/bundleware with e.g. Microsoft Defender or Malwarebytes.

Comment: @Destroy666 Thanks I uninstalled it using Bulk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Bulk Crap Uninstaller](https://www.bcuninstaller.com) is recommended to get rid of unwanted applications and their files, including bundleware/PUP (Potentially Unwanted Programs). It has quite good detection mechanisms and can spot many programs that other applications may not. It has also pretty good leftover cleanup to get rid of useless registry entries, config folders, etc.

To avoid having such applications installed next time, make sure to run downloaded installers very carefully and uncheck/deselect inputs that can be very well hidden. Or just use a package manager like [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), which uses scripts that try to make sure that only the app that you want to install gets installed.

I'd also recommend doing a full scan check of your system with Microsoft Defender and Malwarebytes on top, to make sure you didn't get anything else and more dangerous planted into your Windows, as anything could have also slipped by easily if you didn't notice how this VPN was installed.

Comment: I had this PUP too, uninstalled it with both, BCU and Autoruns (where I found a service from Bright VPN, which I deleted in the registry (yes, that is dangerous). I dont know exactly how it came (maybe with JB Patch 2023.1.x.exe).

Answer (score 0):

Try This ?

> "Autoruns
> v14.09 (February 16, 2022)
> See what programs are configured to startup automatically when your system boots
> and you login. Autoruns also shows you the full list of Registry and file
> locations where applications can configure auto-start settings."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

Note: Be very Careful when using this tool. Don't Unclick anything unless you know what you are doing. You can right-click a file which is shown in the list to choose options, Delete, etc.
Note that if you choose DELETE it finds the file, not just the Registry entry, and deletes the file also, in most cases.